# _Message__decoded_fields AttributeError what does it mean?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

I want to use a Structured Property and have created a very simple example.

```
class StudentScore(EndpointsModel):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
  mark = ndb.StringProperty()

class MyModel(EndpointsModel):
  scores = ndb.StructuredProperty(StudentScore)
```

However I am getting errors when attempting to put().

> AttributeError: 'StudentScore' object has no attribute
>   '_Message__decoded_fields'

Comment: Posting the full stack trace is always better than posting just the very bottom error text. In this case, it's not clear, without any stack trace context, why this error was thrown. Could you also show the code which attempts to call `put()`?

Comment: Any stack trace? Any code?